# Arduino Uno - Can' get LCD Display work crrectly

Tags: arduino-uno

I make an automatic light that's triggered from a Visitor Counter. I use an LCD to show the actual counter state. The LCD does not anly show the actual count but also the numbers before. For Example:

If the counter is actual 2, it blinks between 1 and 2.

This behavior does not occur in the original project where the correct number is shown.

Please, can I know why, and how to fix it? Thank you!

[image: My Setup]

This is the code:

```
//Visitors Counter and Automatic Room Light
//Viral Science  www.youtube.com/c/viralscience

#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(13,12,11,10,9,8);

#define in 14
#define out 19
#define relay 2

int count=0;

void IN()
{
    count++;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Person In Room:");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(count);
    delay(1000);
}

void OUT()
{
  count--;
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Person In Room:");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(count);
    delay(1000);
}

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.print("Visitor Counter");
  delay(2000);
  pinMode(in, INPUT);
  pinMode(out, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Person In Room:");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(count);
}

void loop()
{  

  if(digitalRead(in))
  IN();
  if(digitalRead(out))
  OUT();

  if(count<=0)
  {
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Nobody In Room");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Light Is Off");
    delay(200);
  }

  else
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);

}
```

Comment: What is the actual program? What is the difference between the actual and your program? What is the code anyway?  And do you mean by blinking it shows alternately 1 and 2?  To fix it, probably you have to change the code, or the circuit, but high likely the code. But this 'answer' is as vague as your question I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes sir @Michel Keijzers it keep blinking and shows alternately 1 and 2 . I will try compile a new coding and see what happen . Thank you sir !

Comment: Please add the code ( that is not working ) to the question. You asked why the code does not work and how to fix it. To answer we must know it. Simply, writing new code seems not to be the best strategy. Perhaps it works, but then you don't know why the first code did not. Or it does not work; what will you do then? Please do not report that your second code does also nor work, without showing it here. We can not guess what you have programmed so far.

Comment: I suggested to change the text and the title of the question as I edited it. If I understood it correctly, please accept die update. It hopefully make the question more understandable.  (Although my English is bad.) I have not access to your code, so it remains to you to add it to make the question a lot more understandable.

Comment: No, please do not add the code to a comment. Just edit your question and add it at the end of your question. Then mark the code completely and press the {} button of the online editor. You'll get well formatted code. You have not enough space in a comment. And the code should be part of the question.

Comment: The code you added is the original code from https://www.viralsciencecreativity.com/post/arduino-visitors-counter-automatic-light from which you said it would work. If you want us to find the error you made, we need to see your code, that might be wrong. So please add the code you have changed, and that does NOT work. And the code from the video only works if you have separate doors. One to go in and one to go out. If you pass the two sensors in one door you get an in and an out event. If I didn't missed anything. ;-)

Comment: If you want to say that it works in the video but not for you, than it is perhaps because the author did a trick. He uses a plank to disable both sensors at the same time. Then he moves the plank to only activate one sensor. It depends on which sensor is released , whether the counter was increased or decreased. He simulates the two doors I mentioned. And he had to doo this within one second. Or the counter remains increasing or decreasing.

Comment: For what ever reason `IN()` and `OUT()` get called at the same time. I see no obvious mistakes in the code, do I assume it has something to do with your setup. But your approach won't work anyway, because `IN((` and `OUT()` will get called **as lang as** a person enters/leaves. What you need is to detect signal edges rather than levels (or does your sensor **detect** s.o.passing by and generate such a signal?)

Comment: So what i can do to eliminated the blinking effect on the lcd based on the infrared sensors detection?